# Tcl: Using the unknown command to include dot notation procedures

Tags: tcl

Tcl syntax is very simple and consistant in the sense of its command / arguments structure. Sometimes I miss the dot notation of other languages like ruby. In ruby you can right something like this:

```
-199.abs                                                 # => 199
"ice is nice".length                                     # => 11
"ruby is cool.".index("u")                               # => 1
"Nice Day Isn't It?".downcase.split("").uniq.sort.join   # => " '?acdeinsty"
```

In [Radical Language Modification](http://wiki.tcl.tk/495) and [Let unknown know](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2776) there are ideas of how to modify the language with the unknown command, e.g.:

```
proc know {cond body} {
    proc unknown {args} [string map [list @c@ $cond @b@ $body] {
        if {![catch {expr {@c@}} res] && $res} {
            return [eval {@b@}]
        }
    }][info body unknown]
}

know {[regexp {^([a-z]+)\.([a-z]+)$} [lindex $args 0] -> from to]} {
   set res {}
   while {$from<=$to} {lappend res $from; incr from}
   set res
}

# % puts [1..5]
# 1 2 3 4 5
```

How can I modify the previous code, so I can write commands with dot notation as in the Ruby example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it for *specific* operations, but not all, and there are some syntactic limitations. For example:

```
know {[regexp {^(.*)\.length$} [lindex $args 0] -> value]} {
    string length $value
}

puts [abc.length]
# ---> 3
set thevar "abc def"
puts [$thevar.length]
# ---> 7
puts ["abc def".length]
# ---> extra characters after close-quote
```

That is, the value must still be syntactically-valid Tcl; that last example is not. You can chain the `know` handlers by using `[$value]` instead of plain `$value` in the handler, provided you've got a handler for the base case.

```
know {[regexp {^(.*)\.length$} [lindex $args 0] -> value]} {
    string length [$value]
}
know {[regexp {^(.*)\.repeat\((\d+)\)$} [lindex $args 0] -> value count]} {
    string repeat [$value] $count
}
# Base case for simple words
know {[regexp {^'(.*)'$} [lindex $args 0] -> value]} {
    set value
}

puts ['abc\ def'.repeat(5).length]
# ---> 35
```

Ultimately, while you can do all sorts of stuff like this, it's not how Tcl is designed to work. It is going to be slow (the `unknown` calling mechanism is not an optimised path) and you're going to hit limitations. Better to learn to do things the normal way:

```
puts [string length [string repeat "abc def" 5]]
```

Comment: In short, if you want Ruby, use Ruby.

Comment: If it is the nesting that is making the code appear rather cluttered, then using a control structure type command to rewrite a pipeline like sequence into the corresponding nested commands can be helpful. I use this technique frequently. Check out the Tcl wiki at http://wiki.tcl.tk/17419 for an example.